The value are declared but never read - The link between the services and the controller are not clear
I'm translating a next JS app to node js I've made a service : commentService.js and a controller : commentControllers.js
This is the the service :
const prisma = require('../libs/prisma');

async function createComment(adId, profileId, comment, medias) {
  return await prisma.comment.create({
    data: {
      value: comment,
      profile: {
        connect: {
          id: profileId
        }
      },
      ad: {
        connect: {
          id: adId
        }
      },
      ...(medias && medias.length > 0
        ? {
            medias: {
              connect: medias.map((media) => ({ id: media.id }))
            }
          }
        : {})
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  createComment,
  getAllComment,
  createResponseComment,
  getLikeAndDislikeComment,
  createLikeComment,
  deleteLikeComment,
  createDislikeComment,
  deleteDislikeComment,
  getAllResponseComment,
  createLikeResponseComment,
  createDislikeResponseComment,
  deleteLikeResponseComment,
  deleteDislikeResponseComment
};


This the controller :
const { response } = require('express');
const commentService = require('../services/commentService');

async function createCommentController(req, res) {
    const { adId, profileId, comment, medias } = req.body;

    try {
        const newReport = await createComment(adId, profileId, comment, medias);
        res.status(201).json(newReport);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }

}

module.exports = {
   createCommentController,
    getAllCommentController,
    createResponseCommentController,
    getLikeAndDislikeCommentController,
    createLikeCommentController,
    deleteLikeCommentController,
    createDislikeCommentController,
    deleteDislikeCommentController,
    getAllResponseCommentController,
    createLikeResponseCommentController,
    deleteLikeResponseCommentController,
    createDislikeResponseCommentController,
    deleteDislikeResponseCommentController
};


I am new at Node Js (those are not the complete code it is the beginning and the end), the issue that came to me is that the value is declared but never read
I have changed the controller name at the end of the module export to be sure that my functions are called,
I'm expecting that the values will be read

Solution found !
The controller was the issue, I updated it
const { createComment,
    getAllComment,
    createResponseComment,
    getLikeAndDislikeComment,
    createLikeComment,
    deleteLikeComment,
    createDislikeComment,
    deleteDislikeComment,
    getAllResponseComment,
    createLikeResponseComment,
    createDislikeResponseComment,
    deleteLikeResponseComment,
    deleteDislikeResponseComment } = require('../services/commentService');

